# Adding Multiple MSBuild versions to Jenkins

Tags: .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, jenkins

I have a slight issue.  I am trying to replicate the Jenkins projects from one machine to another (partly to learn Jenkins with).  On the source machine I had the Jenkins MSBuild pluggin installed and on the target I didn't.  I've installed the pluggin on the target machine but something is missing.  On the source machine I have the option "Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild" and then in the "MSBuild Version" drop down I have two options "(Default)" and ".NET Version 4 (64bit)".  On the target machine I only have "(Default)".  Does anyone know how I get that extra option?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the target machine you have to point to the MSBuild executable.
This link should help [Building a .NET application with Jenkins](http://www.functioncore.com/blog/unit-testing-with-jenkins/)

Comment: Specifically, under **Manage Jenkins** -> **Configure System** you should see a section titled "MSBuild Builder" where you can enter the path to the executable. You can enter several paths, if you have several versions installed.

Comment: Its in Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration ->  MSBuild. See here :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37938757/msbuild-plugin-configuration-in-not-available-in-jenkins-configuration-page