# MSBuild plugin configuration in not available in Jenkins Configuration page

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have installed MSBuild plugin for jenkins using plugin management. It was installed successfully and I am able to see the options for MSBuild in Job configuration page.

But,  unfortunately I am not able to see MSBuild section in Jenkins configuration page. I need to provide the path for MSBuild.exe in that section.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This option is available under this section ..

```
Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration ->  MSBuild
```

Comment: I've read lots of blog posts and tutorials that have this wrong. Perhaps it is due to a change in the latest version of Jenkins. This is the solution for configuring MSBuild and MSTestRunner on Jenkins.

Comment: i am using jenkins latest 2.40 version.this is the location for msbuild